# python post with auth

Tags: python-2.7, post, oauth

ok here is my code , what I am trying to do is post to a page that is password protected can you have a look at the code below at see where I am going wrong getting

## !/usr/bin/python

import requests, sys, socket, json
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth ,HTTPBasicAuth

## 172.168.101.214

params = {'@Generate': 'New'}
response = requests.post('https://TerraceQ.internal.ca/views/Debug_Dump/1', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'fakepassword'), data=params)
print response.status_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there this worked

```
ip="172.168.99.99"
try:
    response = requests.get('https://' + ip + '/views', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password'), verify=False)
except urllib3.exceptions.SSLError as e:
    sys.exit('test')
```